# How to update all Id value in associated table(via foreign key) to another value?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

This question might look a bit strange. But let me explain what is my real problem.

In my system, there is Building data that user can freely add data to the system. All of user data will be reviewed later. Sometime, user add building A as "Foo A". Sometime, they add it as "Foo bar A". Both of these record refer to the same real-world object.

For Admin, they need to review all input data and replace all invalid with the correct one. However, after user add new building. They also use this new building in other table like "Order" table.

[image]

I need some SQL script(SQL Server 2008 or later) to update all associated data with the new data. After that, I can safely remove invalid data from database.

Thanks,

PS.1 I have so many table like this. I cannot manually write some script for each table.

PS.2 Column name in associated table might not be "BuildingId" so we cannot use "BuildingId" as search condition to find associated table.

Comment: Is the dependent table's field always going to be the same?  Will it always be BuildingId?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the dependent tables' field name will always *contain* BuildingID, you can use dynamic sql to build your update statements, then paste them into a new code window:

```
USE DatabaseName

DECLARE @OldBuildingID INT = 123
DECLARE @NewBuildingID INT = 456

select 'UPDATE DatabaseName.dbo.' + columns.TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + columns.column_name +' = ' + CAST(@NewBuildingID AS VARCHAR(10))  + ' WHERE ' + columns.column_name + ' = ' + CAST(@OldBuildingID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' AS SQLDeleteStatement
from information_schema.COLUMNS columns
INNER JOIN sys.objects tables ON columns.TABLE_NAME = tables.name
where columns.COLUMN_NAME like '%BuildingID%'
AND tables.[type] = ( 'U' )
```

Comment: This should work for most case. However, I need to use dependent data from current foreign key because some table may not use this name pattern.

For example, table contains 2 different building data like createdAtBuildingId and locatedAtBuildingId.

Comment: I lied, it should be just a small change - see updated script above.

Comment: Your update statement still doesn't use dependent data from foreign key.

Comment: I don't think I understand - don't you want to update all data that was created for "Foo bar A" to instead relate to "Foo A"?  In this case Foo bar A is OldBuildingID and Foo A is NewBuildingID.  Run the scripts to update the tables, then you can just delete Foo Bar A from the Building table.

Comment: As I mention earlier, column name for primary key column is always be "Id". Normally, the foreign key column name normally it name "[PrimaryKeyTable]Id". However, some foreign column name might not use this pattern like CreateAtBuildingId or CurrentBuildingId.

Comment: So, you cannot use '%BuildingId%' as condition to search column name by this.

Comment: you're going to need to add an entry for each form the BuildingId can take, and OR them together.  `...where columns.COLUMN_NAME = 'BuildingID' OR columns.COLUMN_NAME = 'BuildID' OR ...`

Comment: I still need to hard code all possible column name that doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Please see my answer if you curious about how to identify related tables.